# is adding actions, data, and category information to android manifest necessary

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

I was going over some of the Android resources and found something interesting.  It says to add intent filters with the different data, category, and actions capable of the Activity to the Android manifest.  However i've been able to get my app working without adding those things.  Can any one explain if it is required and what adding those intent filters actually does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's required that you have one Activity with the following `intent-filter` IF you want your application to show up on the launcher:

```
    <activity android:name=".YourMainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This let's the OS know which Activity to show when your application is started. NOTE: You don't need the above `intent-filter` if you don't want your application to show up on the launcher (if your application is a widget, for example) (Thanks to Justin Breitfeller).

If you'd like more information on Intent-Filters, check out the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html). A common use is allowing other applications to call your application if it can handle certain operations (such as sending an email, launching the camera, etc). If you declare these operations in your `AndroidManifest`, then your application can be called via Implicit `Intent`s (see the above link).

Comment: Its actually not required to have an Activity with that intent-filter. If you don't have it, your application simply won't appear in the launcher (which may be appropriate if you are deploying a widget).

Comment: Ok now I get it.  I had read the developer docs but couldn't completely understand why they were necessary, or their use.  Thanks

Comment: @JustinBreitfeller This is true, thank you. I'll edit my response accordingly.